# Does "stumbling block" count as an idiomatic noun compound?

Tags: grammar, idioms

What type of phrase is "stumbling block" considered to be? A compound noun? An idiom? A simple adjective + noun noun phrase?

Comment: It's both an idiom and a compound noun (_ing_ verb+noun). I'd hyphenate it "stumbling-block", since it passes the tests for compoundhood. Most dictionaries show it as two separate words.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to say that "stumbling block" is a *compound noun*.

The term is found in English translations of the Bible, and the general understanding is that it refers to a *figurate obstacle* - something that would get in the way of someone's intended path. The expression is translated from a single ancient Greek word, '*skandalon*', which was literally a stick used in an animal trap, possibly the trigger that caused an open trap to close.

As the term 'stumbling block' is a modern English translation of an ancient Greek noun, it should be considered a noun. Even ignoring its origins, I would see it as a compound noun the same as "dining table".